# Trouble with multicast UDP communication on MacOS

Tags: macos, network

I have a small Python script to send multicast packets from Lubuntu 20.04 to a macOS Venture 13.4 machine (script is attached below). The problem is that I am unable to receive any multicast packets on my mac computer and am unsure how to proceed.

I verified that this script works by running the sender and receiver on localhost of my Ubuntu machine but it doesn't work with communication with my Mac across my local network which makes me think that this is an issue with multicast on my Macbook.

---

I see that the MULTICAST option is up on the relevant network interface on my Mac:

`en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500`

---

On Wireshark on my Mac, I am able to see MDNS packets from my Lubuntu machine with destination 224.0.0.251.

---

Here is the relevant part of the sender script host_ip_addr: 192.168.0.101, multicast: 224.5.23.1, 10020:

```
def send_loop(host_ip_addr, multicast_group_ip, multicast_port):
    sender = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM,\
            proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP, fileno=None)

    multicast_group = (multicast_group_ip, multicast_port)

    sender.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_TTL, 1)

    sender.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_MULTICAST_IF,\
            socket.inet_aton(host_ip_addr))

    while True:
        print("Sending data!")
        sender.sendto("test".encode(), multicast_group)
        time.sleep(1)

    sender.close()
```

Here is the relevant part of the receiver script (host_ip_addr: 192.168.0.103, multicast: 224.5.23.1, 10020):

```
def receive_loop(from_nic_ip, multicast_group_ip, multicast_port):

receiver = socket.socket(family=socket.AF_INET, type=socket.SOCK_DGRAM,\
        proto=socket.IPPROTO_UDP, fileno=None)
multicast_group = (multicast_group_ip, multicast_port)
receiver.bind(multicast_group)

if from_nic_ip == '0.0.0.0':
    mreq = struct.pack("=4sl", socket.inet_aton(multicast_group_ip), socket.INADDR_ANY)
else:
    mreq = struct.pack("=4s4s",\
            socket.inet_aton(multicast_group_ip), socket.inet_aton(from_nic_ip))
receiver.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)

while True:
    buf, _ = receiver.recvfrom(BUFSIZE)
    msg = buf.decode()
    print(msg)

reciver.close()
```